# scrape YouTube video from a specific channel and search?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, youtube

I am using this code to get the url of a youtube channel it works fine, but I would like to add an option to search for a video with a specific title within the channel. and get the url of the first video you find with the search phrase

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=LinusTechTips"
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

for entry in soup.find_all("entry"):
    for link in entry.find_all("link"):
        print(link["href"])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my last answer, you get all the video titles in the given youtube channel, as what you looking for
But in the comments between us, you tell me you wanna run the script via `cronjob`, it takes more effort, so I add another answer.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree
import urllib
import requests
import sys

def fetch_titles(url):
    video_titles = []
    html = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
    for entry in soup.find_all("entry"):
        for link in entry.find_all("link"):
            youtube = etree.HTML(urllib.request.urlopen(link["href"]).read()) 
            video_title = youtube.xpath("//span[@id='eow-title']/@title") 
            if len(video_title)>0:
                video_titles.append({"title":video_title[0], "url":link.attrs["href"]})
    return video_titles

def main():
    if sys.argv.__len__() == 1:
        print("Error: You should specifying keyword")
        print("eg: python3 ./main.py KEYWORD")
        return

    url="https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=LinusTechTips"
    keyword = sys.argv[1]

    video_titles = fetch_titles(url)
    for video in video_titles:
        if video["title"].__contains__(keyword):
            print(video["url"])
            break # add this line, if you want to print the first match only


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When you call the script via Terminal, you should specify the keyword, like this:

`$ python3 ./main.py Mac`

Which `Mac` is the keyword and `main.py` is the python script filename

Output:

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_IHSRPVqwQ`

Comment: works like a charm . I just wanted it to only show the first url it finds that matches the keyword.

Comment: If there are many titles that match the keyword, it shows them all. I just want it to show the first one that matches the keyword

Comment: Good news, OK. This is so simple, add `break` after this line: `print(video["url"])`. When first match happens, it will break the loop

Answer (score 2):

This is a good way to do it, but you'll have a lot more leverage using a tool like `youtube-dl`.  Try something like `youtube-dl "ytsearchall:intitle:'hello world'" --dump-json --flat-playlist`.  `youtube-dl` has a ton of functionality and will probably meet all of your video scraping needs with little or no modification.

In terms of implementing your own search- the basics are pretty straightforward, but may not give you the experience you're looking for.  You would want to collect the titles, probably into a dict with values that have the URL, and then you'd need to iterate over the keys searching for text.  Exact keyword matching in this fashion isn't hard, but it may also not be what you're expecting, because most search engines use a lot of criteria to give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Do like this friend:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree
import urllib
import requests

url="https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=LinusTechTips"
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

video_titles =[]

print("Cashing Video Titles ...")
for entry in soup.find_all("entry"):
    for link in entry.find_all("link"):
        youtube = etree.HTML(urllib.request.urlopen(link["href"]).read()) 
        video_title = youtube.xpath("//span[@id='eow-title']/@title") 
        if len(video_title)>0:
            video_titles.append({"title":video_title[0], "url":link.attrs["href"]})
            print(len(video_titles), ":", video_title[0])

print("Cashing Video Titles Done!")


keyword = input("Enter the keyword you wanna search:")
for video in video_titles:
    if video["title"].__contains__(keyword):
        print(video["url"])
```

Output:

```
Cashing Video Titles...
1: The $32,000 Mac Pro Killer
2: Sony PlayStation - by Alienware - WAN Show June 12, 2020
3: Experimental 120FPS Game Streaming!
4: We Edited This Video on an iPad Pro!
5: The Tiniest Gaming Laptop!
6: I spent two days in my attic to avoid a camera subscription!
7: Stolen iPhones Rat Out New "Owners" - WAN Show June 5, 2020
8: We got the GPU AMD wouldnât sellâ¦
9: Will More RAM Make your PC Faster?? (2020)
Cashing Video Titles Done
Enter the keyword you wanna search: Mac
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_IHSRPVqwQ
```

Comment: yes... i want the script to search for the word and display the url

Comment: you can replace upon **foreach loop** with this lambda expr: `result = list(filter(lambda video: video["title"].__contains__(keyword), video_titles))`

Comment: It works fine but you have to press enter to find the url. actually I will use this with a cronjob. I actually want the script to search the first 10 results and display the url of the first result that matches the keyword.

Comment: Would there be an easy way to also scrape the number of "Views" for each title?