# Scrape YouTube video url from a specific channel to Json

Tags: python

I am trying to save the url obtained with this script in a json file. but I couldn't get it

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree
import urllib
import requests
import sys

def fetch_titles(url):
    video_titles = []
    html = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
    for entry in soup.find_all("entry"):
        for link in entry.find_all("link"):
            youtube = etree.HTML(urllib.request.urlopen(link["href"]).read()) 
            video_title = youtube.xpath("//span[@id='eow-title']/@title") 
            if len(video_title)>0:
                video_titles.append({"title":video_title[0], "url":link.attrs["href"]})
    return video_titles

def main():
    if sys.argv.__len__() == 1:
        print("Error: You should specifying keyword")
        print("eg: python3 ./main.py KEYWORD")
        return

    url="https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=LinusTechTips"
    keyword = sys.argv[1]

    video_titles = fetch_titles(url)
    for video in video_titles:
        if video["title"].__contains__(keyword):
            print(video["url"])
            break # add this line, if you want to print the first match only


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

my json file have this simple structure

{"url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxx"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you print the first match and skip others, The whole `main.py` will be like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree
import urllib
import requests
import sys
import json

def fetch_titles(url):
    video_titles = []
    html = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
    for entry in soup.find_all("entry"):
        for link in entry.find_all("link"):
            youtube = etree.HTML(urllib.request.urlopen(link["href"]).read()) 
            video_title = youtube.xpath("//span[@id='eow-title']/@title") 
            if len(video_title)>0:
                video_titles.append({"title":video_title[0], "url":link.attrs["href"]})
    return video_titles

def save_as_json(result, json_file_path):  # I've add this function to save result as json file
    data = json.dumps(result)
    print(data)
    with open(json_file_path, 'w') as file:
          file.write(data)

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        print("Error: You should specifying keyword")
        print("eg: python3 ./main.py KEYWORD")
        return
    json_file_path = "file.json"  # json file path
    url="https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=LinusTechTips"
    keyword = sys.argv[1]

    video_titles = fetch_titles(url)
    result ={"url": video["url"] for video in list(reversed(video_titles)) if keyword in video['title']}

    save_as_json(result, json_file_path)      

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You know what?  I wrote the python code which you mention in your question. It was the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62381342/scrape-youtube-video-from-a-specific-channel-and-search/62430052#62430052) question !!

I've replaced `foreach` loop to a single line `for` and I reversed the list like this `list(reversed(video_titles))` to matching the first result.

Happy coding!

Comment: OK, please post another question, I do my best for you. Here we finished up

Comment: ok check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62545758/scrape-youtube-video-url-from-a-specific-channel-to-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Use this piece of code after you call `fetch_titles(url)`, the import should obviously be at the beginning.

```
import json

# skip

urls = {'url': video['url'] for video in video_titles if keyword in video['title']}
with open('results.json') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(urls))
```

It builds the `urls` dictionary using a dict comprehension, in a single operation. The call to `__contains__` is done via the `in` operand. It then writes the output to a results.json file.

You should also replace the `sys.argv.__len__()` with `len(sys.argv)`, it's the correct, pythonic way how to do it.

Comment: Fantastic, but I think your code pass the last match, you have an assignment whenever a new match happens it overwrites on the last one... but in the code, he looks for the first match,  so you can reverse the list.  `pythonic` was coooool expression