# Scrape YouTube video url from a specific channel to mysql

Tags: python

I would like to use this code and save the url that I obtain in a field of a mysql database.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree
import urllib
import requests
import sys

def fetch_titles(url):
    video_titles = []
    html = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
    for entry in soup.find_all("entry"):
        for link in entry.find_all("link"):
            youtube = etree.HTML(urllib.request.urlopen(link["href"]).read()) 
            video_title = youtube.xpath("//span[@id='eow-title']/@title") 
            if len(video_title)>0:
                video_titles.append({"title":video_title[0], "url":link.attrs["href"]})
    return video_titles

def main():
    if sys.argv.__len__() == 1:
        print("Error: You should specifying keyword")
        print("eg: python3 ./main.py KEYWORD")
        return

    url="https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=LinusTechTips"
    keyword = sys.argv[1]

    video_titles = fetch_titles(url)
    for video in video_titles:
        if video["title"].__contains__(keyword):
            print(video["url"])
            break # add this line, if you want to print the first match only


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have a database called "mydb1". inside this there is a table called "tbl1" the url I want to save it inside the column called "url_1" and the ID is "3"

[image]

Comment: I would be careful about what you do with that data in your database tho' since i'm not sure if that's legal.

Comment: as I know YouTube uses JavaScript to add elements but `BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript - so you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser which runs JavaScript.

Comment: if you have problem to save in database then you should find some tutorial to learn how to work in database in Python (and how to write queries in SQL) and come back when you get error message.

Answer (score 0):

ok, first you should install `mysql.connector`, actually the hardest job is here!
`pip install mysql.connector`
more info at:
[How to install MySQL connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation-binary.html)

after installing add the module then define the `insert_to_mysql` function like this:

```
import mysql.connector # add this module
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree
import urllib
import requests
import sys

# mysql connection setup
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="127.0.0.1",
  user="root",
  password="my@password",
  database="mydb1"
)


def insert_to_mysql(title, url): # define this function
  mycursor = mydb.cursor()
  sql = "INSERT INTO tbl1 (name, url) VALUES (%s, %s)"
  val = (title, url)
  mycursor.execute(sql, val)
  mydb.commit()
  print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")


def fetch_titles(url):
    video_titles = []
    html = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
    for entry in soup.find_all("entry"):
        for link in entry.find_all("link"):
            youtube = etree.HTML(urllib.request.urlopen(link["href"]).read()) 
            video_title = youtube.xpath("//span[@id='eow-title']/@title") 
            if len(video_title)>0:
                video_titles.append({"title":video_title[0], "url":link.attrs["href"]})
    return video_titles

def main():
    if sys.argv.__len__() == 1:
        print("Error: You should specifying keyword")
        print("eg: python3 ./main.py KEYWORD")
        return

    url="https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=LinusTechTips"
    keyword = sys.argv[1]

    video_titles = fetch_titles(url)
    for video in video_titles:
        if video["title"].__contains__(keyword):
            print(video["url"])
            insert_to_mysql(video["title"], video["url"])  # call the function here
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Read this w3 article about pyhon and MySQL - good place for starters:
[python_mysql_getstarted.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp)

Comment: chek errors... https://gyazo.com/258265a934ed953e683589f0bce8f54c